# ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (11599,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (11599,7)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, array-broadcasting

why is this happening? What is the fix? I have tried searching before posting but I am having no luck with finding why this is happening with my code. If someone could look at it that would be amazing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

dataset = pd.read_csv("msft.us.txt").fillna(0)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dataset['Date'] = le.fit_transform(dataset['Date'])
train = dataset[:6386]
valid = dataset[6386:]

#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

x_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60,len(train)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=16)

inputs = dataset[len(dataset) - len(valid) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs  = scaler.transform(inputs)

X_test = []
for i in range(60,inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i,0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)

X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
closing_price = model.predict(X_test)
closing_price = scaler.inverse_transform(closing_price)
dataset['Date'] = le.inverse_transform(dataset['Date'])
valid['Predictions'] = closing_price
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close','Predictions']])
```

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/Machine Learning/Machine Learning Final Project/RNN for Microsft Stock.py", line 39, in <module>
    inputs  = scaler.transform(inputs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 389, in transform
    X *= self.scale_

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (11599,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (11599,7)
```

The above text shows the output error I am receiving. I think it has something to do with how I am reshaping the data. I am trying to get the LSTM to predict the data but I am having trouble with reshaping the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here when you are trying to create a data structure with 60 time stamps and 1 output , you did one mistake inside in the for loop. Here you scaled the dataset, then you named it scaled_data. So

```
x_train = [] 
y_train = [] 
for i in range(60,len(scaled_data)): 
     x_train.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0]) 
     y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0]) 

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train) 
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))
```